# How do you put one button on top of the row with bootstrap btn-group?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 11 buttons in 3 rows and since one is "alone" I want it on top and then two rows of buttons.

I tried all the flex-end and content align classes I know. But none seemed to do what I want. I tried these in all variations:

```
align-content: flex-end;
align-self: flex-end;
justify-content: flex-end;
flex-direction: row;

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" 
id="user_skill_level"> 
... the buttons 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to combine `flex-direction: row-reverse;` and `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` to get what you want.

#### Layout

In order to not to confuse with the default *Bootstrap* style, I created a custom class called `.btn-group-custom`.

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-custom">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 9</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 10</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 11</button>
</div>
```

#### Styles

```css
.btn-group-custom {
    /* 
     * Wrap the overflow in the reverse order so that the "alone" would be on top
     * instead of on the bottom
     */
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;

    /*
     * You didn't mention where to put the "alone" button so I assumed you want it
     * to be on the right side.
     * Displaying the whole row in reverse order can achieve that!
     */
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.btn-group-custom > .btn {
    /* Since you want 5 buttons in a row */
    width: 20%;
}

.btn-group-custom > .btn:first-child,
.btn-group-custom > .btn:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

/* Optional: to make rounded corner on the first and last child */
.btn-group-custom > .btn:first-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: .25rem !important;
}

.btn-group-custom > .btn:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: .25rem !important;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/a3s7zno1/33/

Comment: Thank you, it's almost what I want: It should be Button 1 on top but the same layout, do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Klara: I haven't thought of anyway to do that except putting `order` on each button from descending order. In that's the case, you might as well just put all the buttons in the reverse order to start with on the HTML page, i,e, Button 11, Button 10, Button 9, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the "alone" button has to be in the center. Try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 3</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 4</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 5</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 6</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn">Button 7</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 8</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 9</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 10</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 11</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```